# Jackson fail deserialization if field is not present

Tags: java, jackson

I have a pojo like

```
class Pojo {
    private String string;

    public String getString() { return string; }

    @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.FAIL)
    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

I want to make jackson fail when deserializing if the `string` field is `null` or absent. (i.e. `{"string":null}` or `{}`)

As you can see, I've succeeded in the first goal with the JsonSetter annotation. What I am hoping for now is something like that but for a missing property. I found a few other questions asking similar things but they were quite old and referenced features that might be implemented in the future. With the recent release of jackson 2.9, I was hoping maybe this is now possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@JsonProperty` has a [`required`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#required()) element that can be used

> to ensure existence of property value in JSON

Unfortunately, Jackson currently (2.9) only supports it for use with `@JsonCreator` annotated constructors or factory methods. Since `@JsonSetter` only works with setters, you'll have to do the `null` validation yourself.

For example, you'd define a constructor like

```
@JsonCreator
public Pojo(@JsonProperty(value = "string", required = true) String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("string cannot be null");
    }
    this.string = string;
}
```

If the property is present, but set to `null`, Jackson would throw an `InvalidDefinitionException` that wraps the `IllegalArgumentException` thrown in the constructor.

If the property is absent, Jackson would throw a `MismatchedInputException` stating that a property is missing.

Both of these exceptions are subtypes of `JsonMappingException`, so you can easily deal with them the same way.

---

With this solution, you could also get rid of the setter altogether and make the field `final` if that suited your design better.

Answer (score 0):

You may perform bean validation here by annotating the field of interest with `@NotNull`.
You may remove the annotation from your setter.

```
class Pojo {

    @NotNull
    private String string;

    public String getString() { return string; }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

}
```

Similarly if you want to fail the validation for other constraints like size, pattern etc, you may use similar equivalent annotations [available here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html).